# Issue with %0A in preparing a outlook mail body

Tags: javascript, browser, outlook

I have a script which I run through browser's address bar. This script picks up few names in a web page and will open a new mail window with all the selected names and with some body text.

I'm trying to apply few line breaks using **%0A** to the body content but it is throwing **unterminated string constant** error. How to get rid off this? please help.

Comment: I can provide / add some more info if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Edit **a** tag in

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

like this

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again&body=Hello,%0AHow are you">
```

Comment: Your solution works if I run it from a web page. But I'm running it through address bar.